# clear jBoss DLQ

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jbossmq

Does anyone know how to clear DeadLetterQueue from jBoss? 
When i start jBoss, it is waiting 4 minutes at:

```
12:09:06,281 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
```

and other 4 min at:

```
 [DLQ] () Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
```

and i think that probably i have to clear this queue..but it is not inside jBoss...?

Can anybody give a hand of help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you found will remove messages from all queues, which is not always desirable.

You can also accomplish the same via jmx, by invoking removeAllMessages() on the jboss.mq.destination:name=DLQ;service=Queue mbean.

Or you can eliminate the need to manually flush your DLQ at all -- in conf/jboss-service.xml, add `<TimeToLive>86400000</TimeToLive>` to the `<DLQConfig>` element.  That will expire messages after 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

*If* you're going to solve it via SQL, at least make sure the Queues are unbound at the time and restrict it to the Dead Letter Queue like so:

```
delete from jms_messages where destination = 'DLQ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: There is a jbossdb database:

```
delete  FROM jms_messages ;
```